# iOS app store - app available with gift code only

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I made an app and I want to upload it to the appstore - is there any option to make the app available with a gift code only - (generated in itunes connect - you can't find it on the appstore but the only way to get it is to redeem a gift code)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This sounds more like an Enterprise distribution or something you should do with [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com).

You can use promo codes, but they are limited number (50 per version). Another route that is popular is having the app itself be free with upgrades through in-app purchases that can be unlocked via custom "backdoors" that you would have to program yourself.

Comment: Early access would be classed as 'Beta testers' and is exactly what TestFlight is for.

Comment: As Wain said, "early access" means "beta test". In iOS review guidelines, it is written that "apps that are beta, demo, trial, or test versions will be rejected". Check point 2.9 in guideline review : https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html#functionality

Comment: If a developer wanted to offer Kickstarter backers access to their *complete, finished* app prior to the general public, that would not be anywhere close to being classified as "beta, demo, trial, or test version".  I would like to know if this is possible as well, not a personal interpretation of what "early access" means.

Comment: Not possible if you want them to be able to upgrade in future. You could use promo codes but they are limited number. If the app is free with IAP then you could add a custom URL scheme and a back-door activation. You would need to take advice on whether an enterprise account would be acceptable (updates would be outside the App Store...) @streetlogics